# How to match elements from one column to other columns in R?

Tags: r, string-matching

I am attemtping to match string elements from one column to another, and establishing some sort of link between them. Consider the following:

Database 1, column a:

```
Student name
Napoleon Dynamite
Drake Graham
Michael Jordan
```

Database 2, column a:

```
Napoleon M
Drake H
Michael G
```

Database 2, column b:

```
Dynamite
Graham
Jordan
```

What I am looking to do is to match column a from database 1 to columns a and b form database 2. As you can see, the columns do not exactly match. I attempted to use the agrep function() to achieve this, however I still don't fully grasp how it works.

Comment: If the only difference is that middle initials are added, there are easy solutions available. But if the names are misspelled or other complicating factors, approximate matching is the only way. Will you run into cases like `Nuhpolean` in the second database?

Comment: No, however I am likely to find the following example: Chilli's and Chilli"s. That's why I think it's a good idea to use approximate matching

Comment: Try `sapply(1:nrow(db1), function(x) agrep(db1[x,], do.call(paste, db2)))`

Comment: I get the following:  Error in `[.default`(data$valor, x, ) : incorrect number of dimensions. In my actual case db1 and db2 are not the same dimensions. db2 has multiple repetitions of the names, while db1 is simply an index of all the names, none of which are repeated.

Comment: And you definitely do not want factors here. So when you read in your data make sure `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` is there. They will only increase the headache potential

Comment: They do not have to be the same dimensions. It would help if you posted a sample of your data as it is structured.

Comment: Do this: post in your question the output of `dput(head(db1,20))` and `dput(head(db2,20))` where db1 and db2 are your "databases".